# How to print dynamic forms in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access form where each record has some info that is computed on the fly. I'm using the Form_Current() event; each time a record is selected, I compute some information and change some form controls to reflect it, based on the record's ID.

I want to print a bunch of these records. However, in this situation the Form_Current() event isn't being triggered and the printed records lack that dynamic information.

Any ideas?

Comment: I agree with pro3carp3. If you are looking for alternative suggestions, perhaps you could post some of your existing code?

Comment: pro3carp3's suggestion worked quite well. Feel free to suggest alternatives, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a query that computes the information you need as the source of your report.  You can use vba functions if needed for complex calculations.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. I read through the documentation but I couldn't figure out how to call VBA from an SQL query though. Any hints?

Comment: Create a function in a module and reference it in the SQL.  Here is an example I use to convert from a proprietary date format.  The name of the function is fdConvertTAMDate.  This is what it looks like in the query design window:

TranDate: IIf(IsNull([DATE]),Null,fdConvertTAMDate([DATE]))

Comment: Thanks that worked nicely. My function was in the Form itself, which is why I couldn't call it from the SQL query, I suppose?

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, Luis Oliveira asked:

> My function was in the Form itself,
>   which is why I couldn't call it from
>   the SQL query, I suppose?

By default, functions in a form are private. If made public they can only be called when the form is open, as in Forms!MyForm.PublicFunction(). I would advise against that. Instead, move the function to a public module (which may require revisions to remove references to form controls/fields).